# XSLT Keep some elements and remove others

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to write an xslt that replaces some predetermined tags and completely removes all the others (but recursively applying the same rule to their content).

For example I want to remove all tags except the ones called "domanda". If there is a tag (called for example "risposta") that I want to remove, and it contains a "domanda" tag, the result I expect is that the same rule is recursively applied to the content of the "risposta" element: the "risposta" tag has to be removed but all its textual content and the "domanda" tag must be kept.

I came up with the following (standard) xslt so far, that copies all elements and transforms the ones called "domanda".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="domanda">
        <DOMANDA>
            <xsl:copy-of select="./node()"/>
        </DOMANDA>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="p">
            <p>
                <xsl:copy-of select="./node()"/>
            </p>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How do I complete this xslt with a rule that removes all the non specified tags?

Input example:

```
<testo>
        <p class="p@2">«È una vittoria schiacciante, politicamente schiacciante.
            Al di là dei numeri parlamentari, cioè della possibilità che Syriza
            abbia la maggioranza assoluta». Nichi Vendola, leader di Sel, è
            ovviamente raggiante per la vittoria del leader della sinistra greca.
        </p>
        <domanda class="domanda">Vendola, qual è il segnale che arriva dal
            risultato greco?</domanda>
        <risposta class="risposta">«Il mio primo pensiero va alla riscossa di un
            popolo umiliato dalle politiche dell’austerity europea. La democrazia
            riaggancia la vita e la rappresenta. E apre la possibilità di ridare
            speranza a questa Europa rinchiusa nelle sue politiche, micidiali per
            i popoli e sterili per il futuro».</risposta>
        <domanda class="domanda">Finora però non sembrava che il mondo della
            sinistra europea guardasse con ottimismo alla Grecia di Syriza.
        </domanda>
        <risposta class="risposta">«Invece l’intero Partito del socialismo
            europeo ha tifato nell’ombra proprio per Tsipras. Sperano in Tsipras
            perché sono consapevoli del disastro che ha provocato il rigore
            voluto dalla Merkel, c’è una <p>HELLOOOOOOO</p>voragine sociale che si è aperta sotto i
            piedi della democrazia. Qualsiasi sinistra, anche la più moderata,
            non può non rendersene conto. E non può non vedere che la Grecia apre
            uno spiraglio».</risposta>
        <domanda class="domanda">Tsipras come un cavallo di Troia, per restare
            in tema?</domanda>
        <risposta class="risposta" id="U10401624295425M7">«Semmai come Enea che si carica
            sulle spalle il vecchio padre e ricomincia il viaggio, un nuovo
            inizio».</risposta>

</testo>
```

Expected output (specifying that I want to translate `<domanda>` in `<DOMANDA>` and keeping the `<testo>` and `<p>` tags):

```
<testo>
        <p class="p@2">«È una vittoria schiacciante, politicamente schiacciante.
            Al di là dei numeri parlamentari, cioè della possibilità che Syriza
            abbia la maggioranza assoluta». Nichi Vendola, leader di Sel, è
            ovviamente raggiante per la vittoria del leader della sinistra greca.
        </p>
        <DOMANDA class="DOMANDA">Vendola, qual è il segnale che arriva dal
            risultato greco?</DOMANDA>
            «Il mio primo pensiero va alla riscossa di un
            popolo umiliato dalle politiche dell’austerity europea. La democrazia
            riaggancia la vita e la rappresenta. E apre la possibilità di ridare
            speranza a questa Europa rinchiusa nelle sue politiche, micidiali per
            i popoli e sterili per il futuro».
        <DOMANDA class="DOMANDA">Finora però non sembrava che il mondo della
            sinistra europea guardasse con ottimismo alla Grecia di Syriza.
        </DOMANDA>
        «Invece l’intero Partito del socialismo
            europeo ha tifato nell’ombra proprio per Tsipras. Sperano in Tsipras
            perché sono consapevoli del disastro che ha provocato il rigore
            voluto dalla Merkel, c’è una <p>HELLOOOOOOO</p>voragine sociale che si è aperta sotto i
            piedi della democrazia. Qualsiasi sinistra, anche la più moderata,
            non può non rendersene conto. E non può non vedere che la Grecia apre
            uno spiraglio».
        <DOMANDA class="DOMANDA">Tsipras come un cavallo di Troia, per restare
            in tema?</DOMANDA>
        «Semmai come Enea che si carica
            sulle spalle il vecchio padre e ricomincia il viaggio, un nuovo
            inizio».

</testo>
```

The risposta (but it can be any tag not specified) has been removed.

Thanks

Comment: Better give us an input XML, and its expected output..

Comment: Why is the `p` element still in there? You will need to explain in more detail which elements you want to strip and which ones you want to keep.

Comment: I forgot to add it in the xslt in the answer. I added it now.

Comment: I have rewritten my answer, basically don't use the generic identity template (`match="@* | node()"`) you have first, just list the element names you want to preserve and then add templates for the elements you want to transform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="domanda">
        <DOMANDA>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </DOMANDA>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(self::domanda)]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you can replace `self::domanda` with `self::domanda or self::domanda1` and so on

Comment: I think this works. I'll make some more tests but this should be the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you know all the element names (e.g. `presto`, `p`) you want to preserve then start with

```
<xsl:template match="presto | p">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

then add templates for the elements you want to transform

```
<xsl:template match="domanda">
    <DOMANDA>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </DOMANDA>
</xsl:template>
```

but don't include the generic template you had first.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the name of the <risposta> tag in advance. It could be any tag name. I only know the names of the tags I want to keep.